# Windows Server 2012 R2 Enable Bio-metric

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, biometrics

I have Windows Server 2012 R2 installed on my laptop for development environment, I want to use builtin Bio-metric device to login to computer/server, i can see bio-metric device is properly installed in device manager. When i googled i can see some solutions with domain controller configured and biometric can be configured in Group Policy with a domain user,

But I'm using Workgroup, though i logged in as Administrator i can't see such configurations

My question is can i enable Bio-metrics on Windows Server 2012 R2 or its something that is not used on servers

Comment: You need to install the Fingerprint driver software in the Server, but I doubt it will work. I have not seen Biometric login on any Server 2012 or earlier.

Comment: Its already installed, while googling around i came to know to install some services for domain controller, but i do not have setup domain controller on my system, its just workgroup